# What is the difference between these formulas for standard deviation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, standard-deviation

Throughout my entire math career, I have seen this formula for standard deviation
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\dfrac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}{(X_i-\mu)^2}}{N}}
$$

However now we are going over expected values, means, and standard deviations in probability theory class and learned this formula

$$
\sigma_x = \sqrt{E(X^2) - \mu_x^2}
$$

How is one formula the sum of the differences of the actual value, whereas the other is the difference with the expected value of the variable squared? Are these two formulas equivalent or have I made a mistake?

Comment: Note that $E[(X-\mu_x)^2]=E[X^2]-\mu_x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is 
$$\mu = E(X)$$
and 
$$
\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}(X) = E[(X-\mu)^2] = E(X^2)-\mu^2,
$$
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)} = \sqrt{E[(X-\mu)^2]} = \sqrt{E(X^2)-\mu^2}.
$$
The expression 
$$\dfrac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}{(X_i-\mu)^2}}{N}$$ is an estimator of the variance of $X,$ namely it is the sample mean of the squared deviations $(X_1-\mu)^2,\ldots,(X_n-\mu)^2$ of the observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from the true mean $\mu$. Your expression $$\sqrt{\dfrac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}{(X_i-\mu)^2}}{N}}$$
is then an estimator of the standard deviation but it is not the "true" standard deviation.

Comment: Wow that's crazy, so you're saying that the "normal" formula (the one with the Summation) is only just an estimate for standard deviation? That's crazy to think I was taught a "wrong" thing throughout high school

Comment: It is not a wrong thing, it is a good estimator.

Answer (score 0):

Your first formula for standard deviation can be seen as a special case of the second formula. If you have a list of numbers $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_N$ and you define a random variable $X$ that selects one number uniformly at random from this list, then you can calculate that
$$E(X) = \frac1N\sum_ix_i.\tag1
$$
Using the notation $\bar x$ for the expression (1), you can further calculate 
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-(EX)^2=\frac1N\sum x_i^2-(\bar x)^2=\frac1N\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2.\tag2
$$
So your two versions of standard deviation are linked and not in contradiction. It's often the case that the rightmost expressions in (1) and (2) are introduced as the summary statistics for a list of numbers, in contexts where the concept of a random variable is nowhere in sight. (But of course you can apply (1) and (2) to a list of numbers that were obtained as a random sample $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$ from some larger population, thus giving rise to the interpretation of (1) and (2) as random variables which estimate population quantities.)